# Multiple Jquery DataTables in a Page but on Ajax Error Hide Other Tables and Stop Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am displaying Two or Three DataTables and each of these Tables are Independent of each other and are placed on their own parent container and have their own Ajax Operations. Now my concern is if any of the DataTable's Ajax Operations returns the Failure Response or (Success operations with Failed Data inside it), then all the Tables must be hidden and the Error Message Should display in the Page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [`about`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort)  for cancel XMLHttpRequest are pending status

```js
 example 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
   var requestTable1 = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'someurl1',
                success: function (result) { }
            });
            
    var requestTable2 = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'someurl2',
                success: function (result) { }
            });
     var requestTable3 = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'someurl3',
                success: function (result) { }
            });

    $( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
      if ( settings.url == "someurl1" ) {
      
       requestTable2.about();// and alert msg 
       requestTable3.about();
      }
      else if ( settings.url == "someurl2" ) {
        requestTable1.about();// and alert msg 
        requestTable3.about();
      }
       else if ( settings.url == "someurl3" ) {
        requestTable1.about();// and alert msg 
        requestTable2.about();
      }
      
    });
```

I think it might help you.